# Setting two vertically stacked buttons dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to set two buttons at the bottom of the screen one above the other and these buttons should fill parent width and wrap the content's height. Do I have to calculate the screen height manually for the different screen sizes like I do in my code below or is there another way to get this done and do I have to call `LayoutParams` for each button just to change the `topMargin` slightly?

So far I have this

```
//BUTTON ONE
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams btnParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int marginTop = (int) (350 * scale + 0.5f);
btnParams1.topMargin = marginTop ;
btn_true.setLayoutParams(btnParams1);

//BUTTON TWO
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams btnParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int marginTop = (int) (300 * scale + 0.5f);
btnParams1.topMargin = marginTop ;
btn_false.setLayoutParams(btnParams1);
```

Comment: "On top of each other" regarding y axis or z axis?

Comment: And why don't you use a LinearLayout in this case?

Comment: I used RelativeLayout because the original buttons were in relative, I wasn't sure if that would cause a problem or not in my case as the buttons being moved here were first set in XML then manipulated here.

Comment: Why not use alignTop?

Comment: Want them to be at the bottom of the screen

Comment: I would add a LinearLayout to your xml layout at the bottom. Make the layout fill width and wrap height. Then just add the two buttons to that. You can play around in the layout editor to make sure it aligns right.

Comment: thanks @thomas88wp I already have it set out like that, but i want to move the buttons from those initial positions to match screen width and move down to the button of the screen after I click a button.